# How to Minitest Controller :create action with Paperclip Validators

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, paperclip, minitest

Basically my :create action test keeps failing, even though it works in the app. I commented out the paperclip validations in my controller below and it worked.

```
  has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "700x700>", small: "350x250#" }
  validates_attachment_presence :image
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
```

This is the test I am running, it works when the validations are commented out. How can i pass params that will meet the paperclip validations in my model.

```
test "should create if signed_in" do
      sign_in(@user)
      assert_difference 'Product.count' do
        post :create, product:{ title:'test_product', description: 'khara', user_id: @user.id}
      end
      assert_redirected_to product_path(assigns(:product))
    end
```

FAILURE MESSAGE:

```
    FAIL["test_should_post_create_if_signed_in", ProductsControllerTest, 0.58458]
         test_should_post_create_if_signed_in#ProductsControllerTest (0.58s)
                "Product.count" didn't change by 1.
                Expected: 3
                  Actual: 2
                test/controllers/products_controller_test.rb:52:in `block in <class:ProductsControllerTest>'
```

Basically how do I make this test pass?

NOTE: I am aware that paperclip provides testing instructions with Shoulda and Spec was hoping to do this purely in Minitest.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should just attach an issue using ActionDispatch::TestProcess,   `fixture_file_upload`. Put an image you want to use for your tests in `test/fixtures` adjust your test to look like this:

```
test "should create if signed_in" do
          sign_in(@user)
          image = fixture_file_upload('some_product_image.jpg', 'image/jpg')
          assert_difference 'Product.count' do
            post :create, product:{ title:'test_product', 
                               description: 'khara', 
                                   user_id: @user.id,
                                     image: image
                                   }
          end
          assert_redirected_to product_path(assigns(:product))
        end
```

This will return an object that pretends to be an uploaded file for paperclip.

Comment: Thanks that worked! I had tried `fixture_file_upload` before but i didn't specify the `'image/jpg'` file type.